# Link Access to SQL Server 2008 R2 for easier SQL support/editing?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I am trying to develop a proposal for small biz executives to have access to dashboards for up to date financials.
This data can come from various regional/local offices, to be collected and analyzed at the parent/home office.

--Link specific tables in SQL server to Access

**QUESTION:**   I read this is advisable because sometimes it is easier to edit in Access than diretly in SQL Server.  It makes support easier.  Is this true or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is a nice way to go.  Access offers an excellent RAD environment.
The biggest problem will be when you try to access datasets that are enormous.  You will need to be able to write stored procedures in order to summarize the data before it goes over the wire for Access to process.  If the datasets are big, you will be using stored procedures or something similar to a pass through query no matter what you use for a front end.